# Non static method requires a target

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

```
private PMS_USERS currUser;
private bool validateUserName()
{
    dbContext = new PmsEntities();
    var validateUser = dbContext.PMS_USERS.Where(p=> p.LOGICALREF != currUser.LOGICALREF).Where(p=> p.USERNAME == currUser.USERNAME);
    return !validateUser.Any();
}
```

Hello,
I got an error while validating on my new user register form.

My `PMS_USERS` table has no record(`null`). I also tried checking for `null` control(s) for `currUser`.

What am I missing?

Error is :

> *Non static method requires a target*

Comment: Seems a Try / Catch is needed here...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should first test if currUser is null or not and your dbContext too.

```
if (currUser == null) return false;
if (dbContext == null) throw new Exception ("The dbContext has not been set");
```

Secondly, you can simplify your query like yhat :

```
 var validateUser = dbContext.PMS_USERS.Where(p=> p.LOGICALREF != currUser.LOGICALREF &&  p.USERNAME == currUser.USERNAME);
```

And then change the return statement to :

```
return (validateUser.FirstOrDefault() != null);
```

You can alternativelly use SingleOrDefault statement insead of FirstOrDefault, if you want to be sure there is only one user corresponding to your criteria.

Comment: Can you explain difference between `return validateUser.Any();` and `return (validateUser.FirstOrDefault() != null);`? Why you suggest 2nd instead of 1st?

Comment: In fact, I think it is the same thing. The Any is more simple. The problems came from the Where clause in this problem.

Comment: Adding if (dbContext != null) check worked for me. Can you explain the reason?

Answer (score 2):

"Non static method requires a target" means that some object inside the scope is `null`.

Try checking the context and the var result values:

```
 dbContext = new PmsEntities();
 if (dbContext != null && currUser != null)
 {
     var validateUser = dbContext.PMS_USERS.Where(p=> p.LOGICALREF != currUser.LOGICALREF && p.USERNAME == currUser.USERNAME);

    if (validateUser !=null)
    {
       return !validateUser.Any();
    }
    else
       return null;
 }
```

Check it and tell us if you have the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
private PMS_USERS currUser;
private bool validateUserName()
{
    dbContext = new PmsEntities();
    return PMS_USERS != null 
        ? var validateUser = dbContext.PMS_USERS.Where(p=> p.LOGICALREF != currUser.LOGICALREF).Where(p=> p.USERNAME == currUser.USERNAME).Any()
        : false;
}
```