# C# Query - Non Static Method Requires a Target

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

i am getting an error that says 'Non Static Method requires a target'

Here is the code that is causing me the error, could anyone possible shed some light on this?

```
//TODO: Error, Non static method requires a target.
var orderItem =
    _context.PurchaseOrderItems.FirstOrDefault(
        p => p.JobReference == item.JobReference && p.ItemNumber == item.ItemNumber);
return _context.DeliverySchedules.Include(d => d.PurchaseOrderItem)
           .Where(d => d.PurchaseOrderItem.Id == orderItem.Id)
               .ToList();
```

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Non-static method requires a target.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717355/non-static-method-requires-a-target.

Comment: `.Where(d => d.PurchaseOrderItem.Id == orderItem.Id)` may throwing NRE if `orderItem` has null or no results returned from first query. Try testing null condition before returning another query using `if (orderItem != null)`.

Comment: Change the `FirstOrDefault` to `Single` because in the next line you will get to its properties and you dont want a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `FirstOrDefault` method may return null value if no query results returned there:

```
var orderItem = _context.PurchaseOrderItems.FirstOrDefault(
                p => p.JobReference == item.JobReference && p.ItemNumber == item.ItemNumber);
```

Since `orderItem.Id` throws `NullReferenceException` when `orderItem` is null, it will propagate to LINQ throwing `TargetException` as mentioned in question (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498981/ef-non-static-method-requires-a-target) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094711/non-static-method-requires-a-target) for more info).

Hence, you need to check presence of null value from `orderItem` by modifying second LINQ query to this one:

```
return _context.DeliverySchedules.Include(d => d.PurchaseOrderItem)
       .Where(d => (orderItem != null && d.PurchaseOrderItem.Id == orderItem.Id))
       .ToList();
```

NB: Null checking must takes place before retrieving property `Id` of `orderItem` to prevent `NullReferenceException`.

As an alternative, `if` condition to check against null value may be used without modifying second query:

```
if (orderItem != null)
{
    return _context.DeliverySchedules.Include(d => d.PurchaseOrderItem)
           .Where(d => d.PurchaseOrderItem.Id == orderItem.Id)
           .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `FirstOrDefault` to `Single` because in the next line you will get to its properties and you dont want a `NullReferenceException`